How to extract certain lines of rows from certain to cell with a specific string to a certain cell with a specific string
Extract certain rows from a cell with value "Start" to "Finish"

My current code is giving the result in different columns and is only limited by the rows declared for checking. Seeking help to improve the code to be have the result in one column as seen in sample picture.
Sub SubDataExtraction()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblIndex As Double
    Dim VarResult() As Variant
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim StrSearchWord01 As String
    Dim StrSearchWord02 As String
    
    
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngData = Range(Range("A2"), Range("B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
    Set RngResult = Range("L10")
    StrSearchWord01 = "Start"
    StrSearchWord02 = "Finish"
    
    
    
    
    ReDim VarResult(1 To RngData.Rows.Count, 1 To 50)
    
    'Covering each cell of RngData.
    For Each RngCell In RngData
        
        'Checking if RngCell contains both StrSearchWord01 and StrSearchWord02.
        If InStr(1, RngCell.Value2, StrSearchWord01) <> 0 Then
            
           
            
            'Setting DblIndex for the next row of results.
            DblIndex = DblIndex + 1
            
            'Reporting the values in VarResult (column 1 and 2).
            VarResult(DblIndex, 1) = RngCell.Offset(4).Value2
            VarResult(DblIndex, 2) = RngCell.Offset(5).Value2
                        
                  
       End If
       
      
    Next
    
    'Reporting the result in RngResult properly expanded.
    RngResult.Resize(DblIndex, UBound(VarResult, 2)).Value2 = VarResult



Set rng = Range("L2:S100")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rng
    .Value = Evaluate(Replace("If(@="""","""",Trim(@))", "@", .Address))
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    
End Sub


You can do it by formula.

Here is one way using Excel Formula:


=XLOOKUP("Start",A1:A15,A1:A15):XLOOKUP("Finish",A1:A15,A1:A15)



Good answer by functions only.

I'll delete my answer..... didn't realise you'd posted exactly the same about an hour ago.

Not entirely sure I follow what you're trying to do, but, if all you want to do is copy the values from Column A into another column (Column E in this case) between the keywords Start & Finish then;
Public Sub TryThis()
   Dim R1 As Range, xCel As Range
   Dim Checking As Boolean
   
   Set R1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
   Checking = False
   For Each xCel In R1.Cells
      If xCel.Text = "Start" Then
         Checking = True
      End If
      
      If Checking = True Then
         xCel.Offset(0, 4).Value = xCel.Value
      End If
      
      If xCel.Text = "Finish" Then
         Checking = False
      End If
   Next xCel
End Sub

The above uses your own multi-column source range, & would put items from Column B into Column F (and Column B would require it's Own Start & Finish)
If you did not mean to have a multi column selection then change that line of code to the following
   Set R1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

As already pointed out in comments a formula will work

Please, try the next code. It does not need iteration and should be very fast, even for a large range. It assumes that only such a pair ("Start" - "Finish") exists on the respective ("A:A") column:
Sub SubDataExtraction()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, srcRngSt As Range, srcRngFn As Range, arr
 Const st As String = "Start"
 Const fn As String = "Finish"
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = ws.Range(Range("A2"), Range("B" & ws.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row))
 
 Set srcRngSt = rng.Find(st, rng.cells(1))
 If srcRngSt Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No Start cell could be found...": Exit Sub
 
 Set srcRngFn = rng.Find(fn, srcRngSt)
 If Not srcRngSt Is Nothing Then
    arr = ws.Range(ws.cells(srcRngSt.row + 1, rng.column), ws.cells(srcRngFn.row - 1, rng.column)).Value
    ws.Range("K1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr 'use here the column letter you need
 End If
 
 MsgBox "Job done..."
End Sub

